# Why does the element value in an array is not as expected in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

In the below code, given that:

```
grid = { "010", "101", "010" }
```

I found that under the conditions `i = 2` and `j = 1` the value of `grid[i-1][j]` is `1`, when actually `grid[1][1]` should be `0`.

Why is the value not what I expected?

```
public static int NumIslands(string[] grid)
{
  int num = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < grid.Length; i++)
  {
    for (var j = 0; j < grid[i].Length; j++)
    {
      if (grid[i][j] == '1' && (i == 0 || grid[i - i][j] == '0') && (j == 0 || grid[i][j - 1] == '0'))
      {
        num++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well `grid[i-1] == grid[1] == "101"`, and `"101"[1] == '0'`. Which bit of that is a surprise?

Comment: In your if-statement you say `grid[i-i]`. Typo?

Comment: Yes, I have a typo. I think this question should be closed. Shame for me :(

Comment: There's no shame in a typo. :) You can delete your own question, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you wrote grid[i - **i**] instead of grid[i- **1**]

Comment: Yes, you are right! I am so foolish! :(